# Python: Accessing object attributes from objects stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary, attributes

I have a dictionary with objects being stored as values. How might I access and print the attributes of a particular object? 
For example,

```
dict={0:obj0, 1:obj1, 2:obj2, 3:obj3}
```

I want to print obj1.attribute. I have tried:

```
print (dict[key]).attribute
```

to no avail. I cannot just access the object directly because I have not assigned it to a variable. This program automatically generates objects and places them in dict with an automatically generated key, which spares me manual assignment of an arbitrary amount of values. If anyone knows a better way to phrase this question, please go ahead. Thank you so much!

EDIT: My dictionary's name is not 'dict', nor is my attribute named 'attribute.' These are used simply for clarity.

EDIT: OK, here's what's going on. I'm using Tkinter to retrieve contact information through entry fields. I'm using that input to create an object with attributes name, address, etc. So,

```
class User():

    def __init__(self, name='', street='', city='', state='', zip=''):
        self.name=name
        self.street=street
        self.city=city
        self.state=state
        self.zip=zip

###### code below is outside of class User #####

    def make(name='', street='', city='', state='', zip='', count=0):
        dic[count]=User(name='', street='', city='', state='', zip='')
```

Is there a reason that "dic[0].name" would return an empty string?

Comment: You use `getattr`: `getattr(d[key], attribute_name)`.

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you post a *functional* example of your problem? I can't understand your question with just the code that you've provided.

Comment: The original question is updated, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Johnny_Rose you're setting `name` to an empty string.

Comment: You have set your data to empty strings and asking why it returns empty strings?

Comment: The empty string is the default value, but I'm passing it a very not empty string.

Comment: @Johnny_Rose check my answer, you're not passing it.

Comment: Oh my god. That makes me sick. I've been doing this too much today and I stupidly overlooked that (probably a copy/paste). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
def make(name='', street='', city='', state='', zip='', count=0):
    dic[count]=User(name='', street='', city='', state='', zip='')
```

to

```
def make(name='', street='', city='', state='', zip='', count=0):
    dic[count]=User(name=name, street=street, city=city, state=state, zip=zip)
```

In case your attribute is containing whitespaces or an empty string, you can do that in some case, it will help you know if something is there.

```
print "<%s>" % my_dict[key].attribute
```

If you see `<>` it's likely that this is an empty string, if you see something else in between, it could be spaces are tabs or newlines or anything that isn't visible.

The other possibility is that for some reasons, the `attribute` you're getting is an object that override `__repr__` or `__str__` and returns an empty string. Without knowing with what you're dealing with, it is very hard to help more than that.

Comment: My objects are not saved as dicts, they are saved as the value of a key. So my key might be x, and the value is myObject. I know what attributes are present, I just can't print them. It won't create an error, it will just be blank. If I tried to 

print "Hello, " myDict[key].attribute

and it just prints "Hello, ".

Comment: @Johnny_Rose what does `type(my_dict[key].attribute)` yield? Also if you look into `dir(my_dict[key])` is the attribute you need there? Have you considered that the attribute might be returning an empty string?

Comment: type(my_dict[key].attribute) returns string. I have considered the empty string, but the attribute in question is "name", and I know for certain there is a string of characters in it.

Comment: @Johnny_Rose How do you know it is there? It obviously is not. Show the whole code you are using (trim out things not needed). Otherwise, this is non-reproducible.

Comment: Well it seems 
print "<%s>" % my_dict[key].attribute
returned <>, so I'm going to take another look at it.

Comment: @Johnny_Rose if you can provide an example of the object it would be a better idea, the whole `dict` thing is probably not the issue in that case.

Comment: I have updated the question with a snippet from my code. Thank you for your help.